# linux cluster + want to unlock but from clusvcadm -l I get locked

Tags: linux, cluster

I have linux cluster

when I do

```
  clusvcadm -u
```

I get

Resource groups unlocked

but in order to verify I do

```
clusvcadm -S
```

but I get:

Resource groups locked

why?

in fact the linux is realy lock -:(